# iOS view PDF from a given url inside of an app

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I want to open and show a pdf file from a given url (somewhere in the internet) and view it in my iOS application. Could you please tell me what are the possible approaches to this problem, and list their advantages and disadvantages / limitations? I've heard about UIWebView, are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is using the webview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];   
}
```

If you want to more information please refer the follwing link as well

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html